# Repeat a local notification 3 times

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-firebase

I'm looking for a way to schedule a **local notification** to show 3 times with an interval in between. (want to replace the old notification as well)

I've tried scheduling 3 notifications individually by providing 3 notification IDs and using the same tag. That just displays notification one after the other(not replacing)

Also tried adding a repeat interval. Looks like it works but I cannot give a limit 3 times.

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using for the notifications when you use the repeat interval?

Comment: `code` firebase.notifications().scheduleNotification(notification, {
   fireDate: dateObject.getTime(),
   repeatInterval : 'minute'
  }); `code`